# NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() is not working in flutter and need advise about tab padding/margin

Tags: flutter, tabs, padding

#1. I was making a tab menus using tabcontroller, and I wanted to stop it's tab scrolling ability, and wanted to select tab using tab menu click.

I was trying with physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), but failed.
As a newbie, I don't understand what is the problem or what I am missing!

Here is A GIF file to illustrate my scenario --> [here](https://tenor.com/view/gif-19824684)

#2. In this Scenario, the "Places", means the first tab is maintains a padding, how can I remove it and push it to the left, from where the body started?

Thanks in Advance :)

My Code -->

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() => runApp(StartPage());

class StartPage extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'TravelApp';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(body: StartPage1()),
    );
  }
}

class StartPage1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    dynamic screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    dynamic screenwidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: screenHeight,
        width: screenwidth,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: screenwidth * 0.03,
          vertical: screenHeight * 0.02,
        ),
        child: Container(
          // Places BAr
          height: screenHeight * 0.20,
          child: MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            home: DefaultTabController(
              length: 3,
              child: Scaffold(
                appBar: PreferredSize(
                  preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(screenHeight * 0.076607387),
                  child: new Container(
                    child: SafeArea(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            child: Container(),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: screenHeight * 0.05,
                            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                              0,
                              0,
                              0,
                              screenHeight * 0.02,
                            ),
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: TabBar(
                              indicator: CircleTabIndicator(
                                color: Color(0xFF7675E0),
                                radius: 4,
                              ),
                              isScrollable: true,
                              labelColor: Color(0xFF7675E0),
                              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                              tabs: <Widget>[
                                Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Placess",
                                    style: GoogleFonts.sniglet(),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Tab(
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Activities",
                                    style: GoogleFonts.sniglet(),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Tab(
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Hotels",
                                    style: GoogleFonts.sniglet(),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                body: TabBarView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            width: screenwidth * 0.18,
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    9,
                                  ),
                                  child: ClipOval(
                                    child: Material(
                                      child: InkWell(
                                        splashColor: Color(0xFF7675E0),
                                        child: SizedBox(
                                          width: screenwidth * 0.136253041,
                                          height: screenHeight * 0.076607387,
                                          child: Image(
                                            image:
                                                AssetImage('assets/1002.png'),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        onTap: () {},
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "Mountain",
                                  style: GoogleFonts.sniglet(
                                    color: Colors.black45,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            width: screenwidth * 0.18,
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    9,
                                  ),
                                  child: ClipOval(
                                    child: Material(
                                      child: InkWell(
                                        splashColor: Color(0xFF7675E0),
                                        child: SizedBox(
                                          width: screenwidth * 0.136253041,
                                          height: screenHeight * 0.076607387,
                                          child: Image(
                                            image:
                                                AssetImage('assets/1017.png'),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        onTap: () {},
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "Beach",
                                  style: GoogleFonts.sniglet(
                                    color: Colors.black45,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            width: screenwidth * 0.18,
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    9,
                                  ),
                                  child: ClipOval(
                                    child: Material(
                                      child: InkWell(
                                        splashColor: Color(0xFF7675E0),
                                        child: SizedBox(
                                          width: screenwidth * 0.136253041,
                                          height: screenHeight * 0.076607387,
                                          child: Image(
                                            image:
                                                AssetImage('assets/1013.png'),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        onTap: () {},
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "Location",
                                  style: GoogleFonts.sniglet(
                                    color: Colors.black45,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            width: screenwidth * 0.18,
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    screenHeight * 0.012311902,
                                  ),
                                  child: ClipOval(
                                    child: Material(
                                      child: InkWell(
                                        splashColor: Color(0xFF7675E0),
                                        child: SizedBox(
                                          width: screenwidth * 0.136253041,
                                          height: screenHeight * 0.076607387,
                                          child: Image(
                                            image:
                                                AssetImage('assets/1002.png'),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        onTap: () {},
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "More",
                                  style: GoogleFonts.sniglet(
                                    color: Colors.black45,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            width: screenwidth * 0.18,
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    9,
                                  ),
                                  child: ClipOval(
                                    child: Material(
                                      child: InkWell(
                                        splashColor: Color(0xFF7675E0),
                                        child: SizedBox(
                                          width: screenwidth * 0.136253041,
                                          height: screenHeight * 0.076607387,
                                          child: Image(
                                            image:
                                                AssetImage('assets/1004.png'),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        onTap: () {},
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "Mountain",
                                  style: GoogleFonts.sniglet(
                                    color: Colors.black45,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            width: screenwidth * 0.18,
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    9,
                                  ),
                                  child: ClipOval(
                                    child: Material(
                                      child: InkWell(
                                        splashColor: Color(0xFF7675E0),
                                        child: SizedBox(
                                          width: screenwidth * 0.136253041,
                                          height: screenHeight * 0.076607387,
                                          child: Image(
                                            image:
                                                AssetImage('assets/1013.png'),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        onTap: () {},
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "Beach",
                                  style: GoogleFonts.sniglet(
                                    color: Colors.black45,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            width: screenwidth * 0.18,
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    9,
                                  ),
                                  child: ClipOval(
                                    child: Material(
                                      child: InkWell(
                                        splashColor: Color(0xFF7675E0),
                                        child: SizedBox(
                                          width: screenwidth * 0.136253041,
                                          height: screenHeight * 0.076607387,
                                          child: Image(
                                            image:
                                                AssetImage('assets/1017.png'),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        onTap: () {},
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "Location",
                                  style: GoogleFonts.sniglet(
                                    color: Colors.black45,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            width: screenwidth * 0.18,
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    9,
                                  ),
                                  child: ClipOval(
                                    child: Material(
                                      child: InkWell(
                                        splashColor: Color(0xFF7675E0),
                                        child: SizedBox(
                                          width: screenwidth * 0.136253041,
                                          height: screenHeight * 0.076607387,
                                          child: Image(
                                            image:
                                                AssetImage('assets/1004.png'),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        onTap: () {},
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "More",
                                  style: GoogleFonts.sniglet(
                                    color: Colors.black45,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            width: screenwidth * 0.18,
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    9,
                                  ),
                                  child: ClipOval(
                                    child: Material(
                                      child: InkWell(
                                        splashColor: Color(0xFF7675E0),
                                        child: SizedBox(
                                          width: screenwidth * 0.136253041,
                                          height: screenHeight * 0.076607387,
                                          child: Image(
                                            image:
                                                AssetImage('assets/1002.png'),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        onTap: () {},
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "Mountain",
                                  style: GoogleFonts.sniglet(
                                    color: Colors.black45,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            width: screenwidth * 0.18,
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    9,
                                  ),
                                  child: ClipOval(
                                    child: Material(
                                      child: InkWell(
                                        splashColor: Color(0xFF7675E0),
                                        child: SizedBox(
                                          width: screenwidth * 0.136253041,
                                          height: screenHeight * 0.076607387,
                                          child: Image(
                                            image:
                                                AssetImage('assets/1013.png'),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        onTap: () {},
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "Beach",
                                  style: GoogleFonts.sniglet(
                                    color: Colors.black45,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            width: screenwidth * 0.18,
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    9,
                                  ),
                                  child: ClipOval(
                                    child: Material(
                                      child: InkWell(
                                        splashColor: Color(0xFF7675E0),
                                        child: SizedBox(
                                          width: screenwidth * 0.136253041,
                                          height: screenHeight * 0.076607387,
                                          child: Image(
                                            image:
                                                AssetImage('assets/1017.png'),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        onTap: () {},
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "Location",
                                  style: GoogleFonts.sniglet(
                                    color: Colors.black45,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            width: screenwidth * 0.18,
                            child: Column(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    0,
                                    9,
                                  ),
                                  child: ClipOval(
                                    child: Material(
                                      child: InkWell(
                                        splashColor: Color(0xFF7675E0),
                                        child: SizedBox(
                                          width: screenwidth * 0.136253041,
                                          height: screenHeight * 0.076607387,
                                          child: Image(
                                            image:
                                                AssetImage('assets/1004.png'),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        onTap: () {},
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "More",
                                  style: GoogleFonts.sniglet(
                                    color: Colors.black45,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have `isScrollable: true`?

Comment: @DimaRostopira to align them and in case the tab name excess the limit,then it will hide them, will not break them!

Answer (score 3):

For the tabbar scrolling issue: you will need to set the `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()` in `TabBarView`'s physics property, and not in the `TabBar`'s physics property.